# PHP: Empty result - file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

i am using file_get_contents to run a php script on my website that will export some data in a textfile. The php script "export.php" prints out "OK" when the job is done and "Error" if an error occures.

If i run export.php in my browser it will print "OK" if i run it by calling file_get_contents in another php script the result is empty. But export.php prints in any case "OK" or "Error".

This is my script that calls export.php:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'  => 'GET',
                    'timeout' => 240 
                )
            );

            $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
            $url_pre = "http://";
            $url = "127.0.0.1/export.php";
            $html = @file_get_contents($url_pre.$url,false,$context);
            if ($html === false){
                $job_ok=false;
                $result=error_get_last();
                echo "Error: ".$result."<br />";
            }else{
                if (substr($html,0,2)=="OK"){
                    $job_ok=true;
                    $errurl = "";
                    $result="Job done";
                    echo "Job done: ".$result."<br />";
                }else{
                    $job_ok=false;
                    $errurl = $url_pre.$url;
                    $result=$html;
                    echo "Error: ".$result."<br />";
                }
            }
            echo "HTML: $html <br />";
```

The result of the script is:

> Error:

If i open "http://127.0.0.1/export.php" in my browser i get:

> OK

Maybe someone can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything bad. I never called local files through IP though. Tried to use 'localhost' instead of IP?

Comment: remove `@` from `@file_get_contents` to see if function is returning errors

Comment: i removed the @ from file_get_contents and did not get any error. i also tried localhost but wont work. Maybe the script get any sort of timeout. Because loading the page in the browser will took about 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed file_get_contents to curl and now it works!

```
function curl_file_get_contents($url){
 $curl = curl_init();
 $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5); //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.  

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE); //To fail silently if the HTTP code returned is greater than or equal to 400.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 240); //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.  

 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}
```